# float divs inside position relative div

Tags: position, css-float, css-position

I have a div position relative (id container) and inside it i have other divs (class buttons) that have to be float: left;

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="buttons"></div>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I set buttons divs float: left; they don't compare inside container div, i don't know where they are, even with firebug i can't find them. I i remove float: left; the divs are displayed but one below the other, and not one beside the other. How can i do?
Thanks, Mattia

Comment: Please post the CSS you are currently using

Comment: #container{
    position: relative;
    height: 13px;
    top: 441px;
    left: 1057px;
}
.buttons{
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background-image: url(../images/slider-cmd-not-hp.png);
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

Comment: What is the container supposed to be relative to?
Why do you need the container 441px from the top and 1057px to the left?
What effect are you trying to achieve, we might be able to put a sample together for you.

Comment: continer is inside another div (called slide) and it has to be relative because it's part of a slide (contained in slide div) and it has to stay there when the slide move the elements.

Comment: Here's an image to explain better: mattialori.net/slide.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the style of the buttons class to `display: inline-block;` or use a span.

Edit:

I have put together a jsfiddle example for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/2t87P/

You should be able to tweak the css i hope this helps.

I would also take a look at some of the slideshow addins that other people have developed because my example is not a very good place to start.

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work :(, i think I'll do it with span if i won't find a solution. Thanks